# How to make my aplication open a view over other apps?

Tags: android, flutter, background-process, mobile-application

I'm making an aplication like "uber" and I need that everytime there's a new request for the driver it opens a display for him to accept the request while the app is in background.

How to make it? And there's any way this display can open over other apps?

At the moment i'm just using firebase pushs, but I'd like a faster solution.